# Hibernate in Bitbucket plugin

Tags: hibernate, bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Is there a way to use Eclipselink JPA inside a BitBucket plugin and connect to the BitBucket Database? I'm trying to connect to the BitBucket database using EclipseLink and retrieve the users. I created a User entity class and tried retrieving the users using a native query. It shows the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bull.javamelody.JpaPersistence
```

Is there any way to connect to the database using any JPA framework?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but you shouldn't. Accessing the database directly is not supported. Instead, use the Java API.

Comment: Well how do I include all the required dependencies in the plugin to connect to the database directly from the plugin?